# Программное получение строки по ее имени в файле ресурсов

Tags: java, android, строки

Приветствую, такой вопрос, у меня есть 50 значений строк c именами `name1`, `name2`, и т.д и разным текстом, хранятся в файле `String.xml`. Сначала в `textView` показывается 1 строка с именем `name1`, по нажатию кнопки, `textView` показывает `name2`, и т.д. Сейчас это сделано примитивным способом:
Есть переменная `Count`, при нажатии кнопки `Count` увеличивается на 1 и сравнивается значение

```
 switch (Count) {
                    case 1:
                         textView.setText(R.string.name1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                         textView.setText(R.string.nаme2);
                        break;
                     ...............
```

Но так как значений 50, это делать глупо.

Можно ли организовать что-то типа такого:
`textView.setText(R.string.nаme+count);`     ?

Или есть решение попроще?

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вам 50 строк? Это довольно необычная ситуация. Если это тексты интерфейса, то их обычно выделяют в текстовые файлы и читают через класс Properties. А в андроиде вообще какое-то готовое решение есть для этого. В общем, подозреваю, что существует решение принципиально лучше, чем жонглировать полусотней строк. [Подробней о таких ситуациях](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472)

Answer (score 6):

Прописывать нужные строки в коде и хранить их в памяти не самый лучший вариант.

Вы можете получить содержимое любого ресурса по его имени,в том числе сформированного динамически, через метод `getIdentifier()` SDK, для которого в качестве параметров необходимо указать: само имя ресурса, тип ресурса (string, dimen, color, drawable, id и тд.), имя пакета.
Например, чтобы получить строковый ресурс с именем `name1`:

```
package com.example.myapp;

...

int stringNumber = 1;    
int stringID = getResources().getIdentifier("name" + stringNumber, "string", "com.example.myapp");

TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(stringID);
```

**names.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="name1">String number 1</string>
    <string name="name2">String number 2</string>
</resources>
```

В `TextView` будет выведено: "String number 1"

Стоит заметить, что вы можете поместить свои строки не в *strings.xml*, а в отдельный файл, какой-нибудь *names.xml*, как в моем примере, с аналогичной структурой и поместить этот файл в папку `res/values/`, чтобы не хранить их вместе с строковыми ресурсами самого приложения и удобнее было редактировать.

PS: у вас будет свое имя пакета, указанное после оператора `package` а не `com.example.myapp`

Альтернативным решением может быть парсинг JSON или XML, SDK предоставляет инструменты для этого.

Answer (score 6):

Храни свои 50 строк в массиве строк strings.xml, в виде

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="your_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Обращение к массиву в коде производится вызовом метода `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array);` 
который возвращает массив строк

Comment: +1 Мне немного стыдно, что я придумал решение с Reflction'ом, и об этом вообще не думал.

Answer (score 1):

## Альтернативное решение

Как я уже отметил в комментарии, хранить одновременно все 50 строк в памяти может быть неэффективно, да и код переписывать при появлении новых строк - неправильно. Решение должно быть таким, чтобы при добавлении и изменении строк не приходилось переписывать код.

Поэтому предлагаю хранить строки в текстовом файле и написать метод, который загружает строку по ее номеру. Тогда все 50 переменных вообще исчезают из вашего кода и памяти приложения, а остается

```
textView.setText(loadString(i));
```

## Прямое решение

Положите строки в массив или список и обращайтесь к ним по индексу.

Вот на английском SO я об этом отвечал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864495/2790048

Напрямую обращаться к переменной, имея строку с ее именем, нельзя. Это возможно с помощью пакета Reflexion, но это непроизводительно и чревато ошибками, да и не требуется в данном случае.

Можно добавить все строки или объекты любого другого класса в параметризованный список:

```
int initialCapacity = 50;
List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<String>(initialCapacity);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stringsList.add(loadString(i));
}
```

Если количество совершенно точно не меняется в ходе работы программы, можно использовать массив:

```
String[] stringsArray = new String[10];
for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i ++) {
    stringsArray[i] = loadString(i);
}
```

Теперь к ним удобно обращаться:

```
textView.setText(stringsList.get(i));
textView.setText(stringsArray[i]);
```

Comment: "предлагаю хранить строки в текстовом файле и написать метод, который загружает строку.." в общем то у нас уже есть текстовый файл strings.xml и методы в SDK, чтобы получить из него строку. Писать свои нет особой необходимости :)

Comment: "Напрямую обращаться к переменной, имея строку с ее именем, нельзя" да ну?

Comment: @pavlofff я подозревал, что есть. Не знаю Android SDK совсем.

Comment: @Suvitruf Ну да. Вы же про рефлексию? Я против использования рефлексии там, где она не нужна.

Comment: @NickVolynkin http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435535/15479 ?

Comment: @Suvitruf это не к переменной, а к значению. Разница есть.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно использовать [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), чтобы найти значение свойства `R.string` динамическим образом.

```
try {
    String text = (String) R.string.class.getField("name" + count).get(null);
    textView.setText(text);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // R.string.name{count} либо не существует, либо не является строком.
}
```

Как @Nick Volynkin отметил в коментарии, есть большая вероятность, что другое решение существует лучше хранения 50 строк в `strings.xml`. Если возможно, лучше найти способ кроме Reflection, потому что Reflection выполняется медленно и иногда может быть немного опасным. Но я не знаю детали о вашем проекте, так что не знаю, что ещё рекомендовать вам.

Answer (score 1):

```
getResources().getString(R.string.MyString)
```

Это для отдельной строки, но если вы задали Массив в XML файле, то можно вызвать его `getResources().getStringArray(R.string.MyArrayString)`

Comment: У вас опечатки: `getResources().getStringArray(R.string.MyArrayString)`

Comment: @PeterOlson: исправил.