# Динамическое формирование ссылки на строковой ресурс

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, можно ли сформировать ссылку на строковой ресурс динамически?

У меня есть набор строк. Каждой из которых соответствует своя "шрифтовая" иконка. В названии каждой строки есть цифровой идентификатор - последние 3 цифры.

```
<string name="wi_owm_day_731">&#xf063;</string>
<string name="wi_owm_day_741">&#xf003;</string>
<string name="wi_owm_day_761">&#xf067;</string>
```

И еще у меня есть ответ сервера. Уникальный id из 3-х цифр, которому нужно подобрать соответствующую строку, чтобы назначить правильную иконку для определенного текстового поля.

В самом простом варианте я могу сделать так:

```
id = getId();
if (id == 501) {
textView.setText(R.string.wi_owm_day_501);
}
```

Но из-за того что **таких строк очень много**, получается оооочень длинный код. Отсюда и возник вопрос - можно ли сформировать ссылку на ресурс динамически? Чтобы не подбирать для каждого id свою ссылку, а *составлять* из известной части названия и полученного id. Например как-то так...

```
id = getId();
String temp = "wi_owm_day_" + id;
textView.setText(R.string.temp);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435535/177345

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо эта ссылка дополнила понимание ответа приведенного ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но из-за того что таких строк очень много, получается оооочень длинный код. Отсюда и возник вопрос - можно ли сформировать ссылку на ресурс динамически? Чтобы не подбирать для каждого id свою ссылку, а составлять из известной части названия и полученного id. Например как-то так...
>
> id = getId();
>
> String temp = "wi_owm_day_" + id;
>
> textView.setText(R.string.temp);

Можно вот так:

```
id = getId();
String temp = "wi_owm_day_" + id;
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(temp, "string", context.getPackageName());
textView.setText(resId);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!