# Как поменять фон у кнопки по ее Id

Tags: java, android

Есть 3 кнопки: B1, B2, B3, как создать метод `setEmptyBackground`, чтобы вызывать его в коде, например `setEmptyBackground(B1)` и он меняет фон у 1 кнопки,
`setEmptyBackground(B2)` - у второй. Вот это не работает:

```
public void setEmptyBackground(Button button) {
    Button door = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    door.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dooremty); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы были на верном пути. Вы хотите вот так?

```
public void setEmptyBackground(Button button) {
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dooremty);
}
```

В данном случае в метод передаётся уже определённый `button`, к которому можно применять все методы, применимые к обычному `button`.

А вызывать данный метод Вы сможете вот так:

```
Button door = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
setEmptyBackground(door);
```

**UPD**

Если Вы хотите передавать в функцию только `id` кнопки, то Вам подойдёт другой код, который я напишу ниже:

```
public void setEmptyBackground(int id) {
    Button button= (Button)findViewById(id);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dooremty);
}
```

И вызывать его надо будет так:

```
setEmptyBackground(R.id.button);
```

Comment: Отлично сработало! Спасибо! А как бы еще сделать вот что: я вызываю метод для каждой кнопки        
       setEmptyBackground(R.id.B1); 
       setEmptyBackground(R.id.B2);                
       setEmptyBackground(R.id.B3);                                                           
       а как сделать ссылку                          
       setEmptyBackground(R.id.Bi); где i меняется от 1 до 3?

Answer (score 4):

**UPD** Обновил, что бы параметр был id

```
private int transparentColor;        

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    transparentColor = getColor(android.R.color.transparent);
    setEmptyBackground(R.id.b1);//или R.id.b2 или R.id.b3
}

public void setEmptyBackground(int buttonId) {
    findViewById(buttonId).setBackgroundColor(transparentColor); 
}
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, даже вперёд меня ответить успели =)

Comment: @EgorRandomize =)

Comment: Ок! А как можно еще упростить: хочу сделать так:                                    
     b = findViewById(R.id.bi); а i чтобы можно было подставлять от 1 до 3?

Comment: @СергейФилиппов Сделал передачу id как параметр

Comment: @СергейФилиппов что вы имеете ввиду под 'i' не ясно

Comment: Я может не так выражаюсь: у меня 3 кнопки b1, b2, b3. случайно выбирается число i от 1 до 3. и меняется фон у кнопки bi. можно конечно через if сделать, но я хочу, чтобы метод работал так setEmptyBackground(R.id.bi), это возможно?

Comment: @СергейФилиппов Это уже другой вопрос. Его нужно в отдельной теме задавать. А вообще просто генериуйте число от 1 до 3 и используйте if. Если один из ответов вам помог, отметте его галочкой

Comment: @СергейФилиппов Смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435535/177345), как получить ID ресурса динамически из его имени

Answer (score 0):

```
door.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // из android.graphics.Color
```

или

```
door.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```